# Custom DataGrid Control WPF

Tags: wpf, custom-controls, datagridcolumnheader

I'm trying to create a custom datagrid control for my application. But I've encountered a problem for which I have no idea what is the problem. For some reason the changes I try to apply to the column header just wont apply to my control. 
If I try changing DataGrid style/template it works just fine, but for DataGrid column header it just wont budge. I've even tried to copy the existing default template and changing just the basics of it and it still won't do anything.

I would really appreciate any thoughts/help.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Found solution that fixed problem. In datagrid style i've specified static resource for columnheader style.